# add fee not work in payment price in woocommerce checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I use woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees action to add extra custom fee (with custom input) to order in woocommerce checkout page in update_order_review action.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'prefix_add_discount_line' );
function prefix_add_discount_line( $cart ) 
    {
        parse_str($_POST['post_data'], $posted_data);
        if( isset($posted_data['isWallet']) )
        {
            WC()->cart->add_fee( 'wallet', -$posted_data['walletUsed'] );
        }
    }
```

It works and changes the price in woocommerce checkout.
But when i go to payment gateway, added fee not add to total price.
pls help tanx.

Comment: I have tested and worked fine for me. Please add complete code in your question.

Comment: @Bhautik, tnx i solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solved the problem.
When we click in place order button, new ajax request sends with another posted data (custom data send directly as post data not post_data param).
And i set a condition to it and solved:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'prefix_add_discount_line' );
function prefix_add_discount_line( $cart ) 
{
   if(isset($_POST['post_data'])) 
   {
        parse_str($_POST['post_data'], $posted_data);
        if( isset($posted_data['isWallet']) )
        {
            WC()->cart->add_fee( 'wallet', -$posted_data['walletUsed'] );
        }
    }
        
    if(isset($_POST['isWallet'])) 
    {
        WC()->cart->add_fee( 'wallet', -$_POST['walletUsed'] );
    }
}
```